# gcc with intel x86-32 bit assembly : accessing C function arguments

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, osdev

I am doing an operating system implementation work. 
Here's the code first :

```
//generate software interrupt
void generate_interrupt(int n) {

    asm("mov al, byte ptr [n]");
    asm("mov byte ptr [genint+1], al");
    asm("jmp genint");
    asm("genint:");
    asm("int 0"); 
}
```

I am compiling above code with `-masm=intel` option in gcc. Also, 
this is not complete code to generate software interrupt.
My problem is I am getting error as `n undefined`, how do I resolve it, please help?

Also it promts error at link time not at compile time, below is an image[image]

Comment: Read the [extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) chapter in the gcc manual. PS: unfortunately x86 `int` instruction does not take a register argument so you might want to limit your function to a few special cases unless you are happy with self-modifying code. Normally `int3` and possibly an interrupt for system call should be enough.

Comment: What is it you want this code to actually do?

Comment: @MichaelPetch edited.

Comment: @Jester that is for AT and T assembly, here it is intel assembly.

Comment: And do leave a comment for downvote, it would be less DEMOTIVATING

Comment: So you are trying to generate a call to an interrupt dynamically using self modifying code?

Comment: yes, but with intel assembly embeded in c with gcc compiler.

Comment: @sneh_m no, that is unrelated to the syntax flavor used. It's for gcc inline assembly, **both** for at&t and intel. Anyway, as I said, think twice whether you really need this to be super generic so you can avoid self modifying code.

Comment: 'operating system implementation' and 'self-modifying code' are exclusive.  It's not thread-safe.  Also, you have a 'byte ptr' qualifier on an integer access.

Comment: If you really must call an interrupt whose number is not known until runtime, use a table of interrupt calls and JMP/RET's.  There's only 256 of them, at most.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using GCC, you must use [GCC-style extended `asm`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) to access variables declared in C, even if you are using Intel assembly syntax.  The ability to write C variable names directly into an assembly insert is a feature of MSVC, which GCC does not copy.

For constructs like this, it is also important to use a *single* assembly insert, not several in a row; GCC can and will rearrange assembly inserts relative to the surrounding code, including relative to other assembly inserts, unless you take specific steps to prevent it.

This particular construct should be written

```
void generate_interrupt(unsigned char n)
{
    asm ("mov byte ptr [1f+1], %0\n\t"
         "jmp 1f\n"
         "1:\n\t"
         "int 0"
         : /* no outputs */ : "r" (n));
}
```

Note that I have removed the initial `mov` and any insistence on involving the A register, instead telling GCC to load `n` into any convenient register for me with the `"r"` input constraint.  It is best to do as little as possible in an assembly insert, and to leave the choice of registers to the compiler as much as possible.

I have also changed the type of `n` to `unsigned char` to match the actual requirements of the INT instruction, and I am using the `1f` [local label](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html) syntax so that this works correctly if `generate_interrupt` is made an inline function.

Having said all that, I implore you to find an implementation strategy for your operating system that does not involve self-modifying code.  Well, unless you plan to [get a whole lot more use out of the self-modifications](http://valerieaurora.org/synthesis/SynthesisOS/index.html), anyway.

Comment: The jump is important to flush the prefetch queue because the code modified itself.

Comment: Since this is tagged osdev I assume he's writing his own operating system.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Doh, quite right, I put the jump back.  I don't see that any of what I wrote is invalidated by OP writing their own operating system, though.

Comment: This answer complemeted by  [this aricle](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) solved my problem. Thank you Zwol and @Jester

Comment: In practice on real modern x86 CPUs you don't need a `jmp`, stale instruction-fetch is impossible.  But yes in theory / on paper the `jmp` (or even a fully serializing instruction) is needed.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an answer to your specific question about passing parameters into inline assembly (see @zwol's answer). This addresses using self modifying code unnecessarily for this particular task.

---

### Macro Method if Interrupt Numbers are Known at Compile-time

An alternative to using self modifying code is to create a *C* macro that generates the specific interrupt you want. One trick is you need to a macro that converts a number to a string. Stringize macros are quite common and documented in the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html).

You could create a macro `GENERATE_INTERRUPT` that looks like this:

```
#define STRINGIZE_INTERNAL(s) #s
#define STRINGIZE(s) STRINGIZE_INTERNAL(s)

#define GENERATE_INTERRUPT(n) asm ("int " STRINGIZE(n));
```

`STRINGIZE` will take a numeric value and convert it into a string. `GENERATE_INTERRUPT` simply takes the number, converts it to a string and appends it to the end of the of the `INT` instruction.

You use it like this:

```
GENERATE_INTERRUPT(0);
GENERATE_INTERRUPT(3);
GENERATE_INTERRUPT(255);
```

The generated instructions should look like:

```
int    0x0
int3
int    0xff
```

---

### Jump Table Method if Interrupt Numbers are Known Only at Run-time

If you need to call interrupts only known at run-time then one can create a table of interrupt calls (using `int` instruction) followed by a `ret`. `generate_interrupt` would then simply retrieve the interrupt number off the stack, compute the position in the table where the specific `int` can be found and `jmp` to it.

In the following code I get GNU assembler to generate the table of 256 interrupt call each followed by a `ret` using the [`.rept` directive](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/as_7.html#SEC110). Each code fragment fits in 4 bytes. The result code generation and the `generate_interrupt` function could look like:

```
/* We use GNU assembly to create a table of interrupt calls followed by a ret
 * using the .rept directive. 256 entries (0 to 255) are generated.
 * generate_interrupt is a simple function that takes the interrupt number
 * as a parameter, computes the offset in the interrupt table and jumps to it.
 * The specific interrupted needed will be called followed by a RET to return
 * back from the function */

extern void generate_interrupt(unsigned char int_no);
asm (".pushsection .text\n\t"

     /* Generate the table of interrupt calls */
     ".align 4\n"
     "int_jmp_table:\n\t"
     "intno=0\n\t"
     ".rept 256\n\t"
         "\tint intno\n\t"
         "\tret\n\t"
         "\t.align 4\n\t"
         "\tintno=intno+1\n\t"
     ".endr\n\t"

     /* generate_interrupt function */
     ".global generate_interrupt\n"  /* Give this function global visibility */
     "generate_interrupt:\n\t"
#ifdef __x86_64__
     "movzx edi, dil\n\t"              /* Zero extend int_no (in DIL) across RDI */
     "lea rax, int_jmp_table[rip]\n\t" /* Get base of interrupt jmp table */
     "lea rax, [rax+rdi*4]\n\t"        /* Add table base to offset = jmp address */
     "jmp rax\n\t"                     /* Do sepcified interrupt */
#else
     "movzx eax, byte ptr 4[esp]\n\t"    /* Get Zero extend int_no (arg1 on stack) */
     "lea eax, int_jmp_table[eax*4]\n\t" /* Compute jump address */
     "jmp eax\n\t"                       /* Do specified interrupt */
#endif
     ".popsection");

int main()
{
    generate_interrupt (0);
    generate_interrupt (3);
    generate_interrupt (255);
}
```

If you were to look at the generated code in the object file you'd find the interrupt call table (`int_jmp_table`) looks similar to this:

```
00000000 <int_jmp_table>:
   0:   cd 00                   int    0x0
   2:   c3                      ret
   3:   90                      nop
   4:   cd 01                   int    0x1
   6:   c3                      ret
   7:   90                      nop
   8:   cd 02                   int    0x2
   a:   c3                      ret
   b:   90                      nop
   c:   cc                      int3
   d:   c3                      ret
   e:   66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
  10:   cd 04                   int    0x4
  12:   c3                      ret
  13:   90                      nop

  ...
  [snip]
```

Because I used `.align 4` each entry is padded out to 4 bytes. This makes the address calculation for the `jmp` easier.

Comment: Presumably, the OP's desired interrupt number is not known until runtime.

Comment: @MartinJames I made a note of that in the preamble already. I don't know the context of his usage. I was putting it out there as an example. If they are known at compile time this is an option.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a better alternative @MichaelPetch I will try this some other time :)

Comment: @zwol between functions GCC doesn't necessarily guarantee which section is set at any point in a source file. There was a discussion about this on the GCC mailing list years ago. I use push/pop section to ensure any of the global assembly code is in the text section. Only a precaution. It is likely it is the text section already, but I don't take any chances it isn't.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code initially. I would urge you to put the jump table inside a function body and use C to handle the argument passing.  This eliminates the need for the pushsection/popsection directives and should also make the code 32/64-bit agnostic.

Comment: @zwol, if most versions of GCC supported the naked attribute for x86 (only 8.x+ does) targets I would have written it as a naked function with the JMP. Problem is that with my method where the jump table has its own `ret` instructions embedded in it I need to ensure that the compiler has done nothing else with the stack. The only way to guarantee the stack is as expected is to simply code the assembly directly. In a C function GCC is free to do anything on the stack after function entry and before the JMP. Generally it won't, but the compiler makes no such guarantees.

Comment: Usually I just toss this type of code in a separate assembly file and link it with _C_.

Comment: Nothing of course prevents anyone from creating the table in _C_, and the code strictly in _C_